# Do you like this idea? (About threads)

Tags: .net, multithreading

Would it not be nice to be able to start a thread like this.

```
Sub DoStuff()
    Using MyThead = New Threading.Thread()
       'Do stuff on MyThread.
    End Using
End Sub
```

It is much less code to write and looks nicer than:

```
Sub DoStuff()
    Dim MyThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf DoStuffThread)
    MyThread.Start()
End Sub

Sub DoStuffThread()
    'Do Stuff
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is already possible (with a bit more noise) in C# using anonymous delegates:

```
new Thread(() => {
  // do stuff on thread
}).Start();
```

and will be supported in VB 10 via multiline lambdas:

```
New Thread(Sub()
             ' do stuff on thread
           End Sub).Start()
```

(I may have the VB syntax wrong, I haven't really played with VB 10.)

Answer (score 1):

So in your example ... a thread would be created that contained the code down to the End Using and begin execution in parallel?

No, I don't like that at all, it's much, much less clear what's happening. If you imagine it working differently please update your question to describe your concept.

Answer (score 1):

When does the code after `End Using` run? Does it wait until the thread finished, or does the `Using` block return immediately? If it waits until the thread finishes, then what's the point of launching a thread at all? But if it *doesn't* wait, then what do you do if you want to get the thread's return value?

There do exist more elegant idioms for threads than the standard one that you mention. In C#, for example, you can use an anonymous delegate to do much the same thing, and C# 4.0 has a variety of threading-related tools. But your example does not illustrate one of them.

Comment: Well let me know some other way to do this then. I find the conventional method for doing this not very elegant.